# Bloco de código em HTML/PHP

Tags: html

Tenho uma página em HTML, e gostaria de adicionar um bloco com código em alguma linguagem, de maneira que ficasse esteticamente bonito como se estivesse no editor de código. sei que a tag `<pre></pre>` é usada mais ou menos para isso.

o que eu queria mesmo era algum plugin, ou algo como esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente usar https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Comment: Era justamente esse termo que eu estava procurando "code prettify".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conheço um plugin em js que atende sua necessidade o [preCode.js](https://github.com/leeoniya/preCode.js?files=1)